# Chrome Extension to Connect to Google Talk

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, xmpp, google-talk, strophe

I am developing a Chrome Extension and would like the ability for the client to connect and chat in Google Talk directly without the help of an external server. What's the simplest way to go about this? I want to be able to customize additional functionalities for my extension (auto-reply, modified presence notification, automated login, etc.). I found some open-source XMPP web client projects like Strophe.js, Converse.js, Salut a Toi, Candy, etc., but I'm wondering which one would be easiest to modify for what I want to implement.

Thank you very much,

Nae

Comment: I have a domain name, but I don't want to pay $5/user/month, because that's definitely going to escalate quickly...